# Select lines by condition and count with one line command

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I need help with analyze nginx logs. Sample of log:

```
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=100&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=500&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
11.11.11.11 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=10&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
12.12.12.12 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=500&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
13.13.13.13 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
```

Is it possible to select with count all uniq ip addresses which contain per_page parameter and this parameter equal or greater than 100?

So, the output can be in any format:

```
10.10.10.10 - 2 # ip 10.10.10.10 was found twice
12.12.12.12 - 1
```

Is it possible to get with one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/per_page=[0-9]{3}/{cnt[$1]++} END{for (ip in cnt) print ip, cnt[ip]}' file
12.12.12.12 1
10.10.10.10 2
```

This is absolutely basic awk - read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to be any other text file processing in UNIX.

Comment: Then your real input file is not as shown or your awk is broken or non-POSIX at least. If you'd like help then just stating `empty result :(` without so much as a thanks for trying or any apparent attempt to debug the problem yourself, never mind actually trying to solve it yourself, is NOT the way to get it.

Comment: This is very strange for me :) I create a sample text file with my first example and run the command. All works good. Then I added one line from real log file and run the command again - all works fine again! But when I run this command with real file - it nothing shown :(

Comment: And one more remark - /per_page=[0-9]{3,}/ should be better

Comment: `{3,}` is not better than `{3}` for identifying "at least 3 digits" unless you are using it in a capture group, which you aren't, and if you need `--posix` to enable RE intervals then you should use `--re-interval` instead to avoid disabling all the other useful gawk functionality but more importantly you should get a newer version of gawk as you are on a VERY old one and missing a lot of useful functionality.

Comment: One more question - is any solution for display captured match by regex?   Example of output what I want - 10.10.10.10 - per_page=100 - 2, 12.12.12.12 - per_page=500 - 1

Comment: yes, match()+substr(). With a more recent gawk you can just use the 3rd arg to match() instead of substr(). Ask a new question if you want more help and include in your sample input/output cases where the same IP address has both 100 and 200 values, for example, so we can see what you want output for that case.

Comment: Added new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157629/select-lines-by-condition-with-formatted-output