# Select lines by condition with formatted output

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

[In additional for my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134001/select-lines-by-condition-and-count-with-one-line-command)

Here is example of log:

```
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=100&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=500&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=100&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
11.11.11.11 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=10&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
12.12.12.12 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example?page=&per_page=500&scopes= HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
13.13.13.13 - - [21/Mar/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /example HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "" "1.1.1.1"
```

With following command

```
awk --re-interval '/per_page=[0-9]{3}/{cnt[$1]++} END{for (ip in cnt) print ip, cnt[ip]}' file
```

I can get counted and groupped result of each IPs witch cosist per_page >= 100 in parameters:

```
12.12.12.12 1
10.10.10.10 3
```

How I can modify it for output with per_page parameter value? For example (any format):

```
12.12.12.12 - per_page-500 - 1
10.10.10.10 - per_page-100 - 2
10.10.10.10 - per_page-500 - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk --re-interval -v OFS=' - ' '
     match($0,/per_page=[0-9]{3}/){cnt[$1 OFS substr($0, RSTART,RLENGTH)]++}
                               END{for (ip in cnt) print ip, cnt[ip]}' file

12.12.12.12 - per_page=500 - 1
10.10.10.10 - per_page=500 - 1
10.10.10.10 - per_page=100 - 2
```

Comment: `{3}` should be `{3,}` in case the OP has values over 999.